# ClassNotFoundException for OracleConnection$CommitOption when using EntityManager

Tags: maven, jpa, ejb, ear, ojdbc

I'm trying to learn the JPA and Oracle DB. I made a maven ear project with an ejb, shared and a web module. I added a glassfish-resources.xml that contains a jdbc connection pool and a jdbc resource to an Oracle database. I can make it work using the DataSource class and JDBC, but when I add an EntityManager to the EJB class (without using it yet), and add a persistence.xml I get the exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection$CommitOption`. This class is part of the ojdbc-6.jar downloaded from the oracle site and is in the lib folder of my ear. The jar is also added to the ear's Class-Path in its manifest. I've no idea how to make this work.

Comment: You probably have to buy a specific licence for that option.

Comment: Is that possible? I thought Hibernate used JDBC in the background. How could Oracle DB find out whether it gets Hibernate queries or normal JDBC queries?